# Bounding the parameters of a multinomial variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose I have a multinomial random variable X whose value range over ${A,B,C}$. After seeing $n$ data points I determine the parameter of the distribution to be $\{p_A,p_B,p_C\}$ through MLE. How do I find the probability that each $p_x$ deviates from the true parameter by some amount? Does Hoeffding bound apply here?

Comment: If you just single out one parameter, say considering $\Pr\{|\hat{p}_A - p_A| > \varepsilon\}$, then you just reduce back to the old binomial case, which either you can use normal approximation, exact method and express as a series. So Hoeffding's inequality apply too. If you consider the joint probability, you can still apply the multivariate CLT and use multivariate normal approximation,

Comment: So if I have three parameters so that $p_A + p_B + p_C = 1$, I can run Hoeffding bound on $p_A$ and $p_B$ separately? Then is it possible or does it make sense to bound $p_C$?  Since it is completely determined by the other two values.

Comment: The problem arise when you want to bound something like $\Pr\{|\hat{p}_A - p_A| > \varepsilon, |\hat{p}_B - p_B| > \varepsilon\}$ since they are not independent. You will need some generalization.